# blender crashing on rendering amimation

Tags: rendering, animation

Blender is crashing immediately upon rendering this simple animation. No error or anything, just crash. I am on an iMac macOS High Sierra i5 4560s I believe.
http://www.mediafire.com/file/t4156hjm2vdk7ml/Dual%2330.blend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this settings all worked fine.

FFmpeg video, mpeg4, h264.

What settings for output are you using?

See the iamge below:

[image]